# Checking if Booting Server is Ready for SSH with Java

Tags: java, ssh

I'm wanting to use Java to check if a server that's in a state of booting up is reachable yet via SSH (port 22).  Currently, I'm just looping using the `isReachable` method like so ...

```
reachable = InetAddress.getByName(host).isReachable(timeout);
```

But this of course doesn't specifically check SSH port 22, so my Java application may jump the gun and try to SSH into the host when it's "reachable" but not necessarily via SSH.  Any recommendations for how best to check if a server is ready to be SSH'ed into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to specifically check for port 22, you could use standard Java Sockets, e.g.:

```
Socket socket = null;
boolean reaching = false;
try {
    socket = new Socket("yourserver.com", 22);
    reaching = true;
}catch(Exception e){
    reaching = false;
}finally{
    if(socket != null){
        try { 
            socket.close();
        }catch(IOException e){}
    }
}

System.out.println(reaching);
```

In order to avoid unpleasant blocking, you could also set a timeout:

```
try {
    int timeout = 3000; // timeout in ms
    socket = new Socket();
    socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress("yourserver.com",22), timeout);
    reaching = true;
} catch(Exception e) {
    reaching = false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Would you mind integrating that timeout code into your above solution?

Comment: @user2150250 I added a more detailed example using timeouts (simply replace the try-catch-block in the above solution with it). Hope this helps.

Comment: One more question, is there any reason you can't just include the socket closing right after the `reaching = true;` line?  The socket must not be null to get to that point anyways no?

Comment: In case of an unexpected exception you might not reach the `reaching=true` line. Placing the socket `close` statement behind the first try-catch block ensures that no matter which exception occurs, you will attempt to close the socket in any case (if it exists). I changed the above example and placed the `close` statement inside a `finally` block. This is better style and might be more intuitive.